# Dynamic routing handling in web config

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have built up a project and deployed it in iis server and the **web.config** file looks like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="about" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^about$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/about.html" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="contact" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^contact$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/contact.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Folder structure.

[image]

This above code works fine if we navigate to `https://your-site.com/contact` or `https://your-site.com/about` .

Same way I also have dynamic routing like `toolboxlinks/[toolboxlinks].html`

Folder structure (On click the toolboxlinks folder from above screenshot, it results in)

[image]

For above scenario, I have included the rule like,

```
    <rule name="toolboxlinks" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^toolboxlinks/[toolboxlinks]$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="toolboxlinks/[toolboxlinks].html" />
    </rule>
```

But it doesn't work and throws `404 error` like,

[image]

I am entirely new to this scenario, So how to get rid of this error for dynamic routing?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Can you tell me which url do you want to rewrite to another? or you can use FRT to check the cause of the 404 error. If you still can’t solve the problem, please explain your needs in detail, i can make demo for you.

Comment: @samwu, Thanks for your inputs and I have already solved the issue..

Comment: @Undefined how did you end up resolving this? I'm currently having the same issue with a dynamic route on IIS